# Python - overtime pay compute using def & return function

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to the python and have a question on python practice I am working on!
Rate is given to 10.5 and hour is 45 hours. Pay should be $498.75 but my code below keeps showing $551.25...

Am I missing anything?

```
def computepay(hrs, rate):
    if hrs <=40:
        pay = hrs * rate
    elif hrs > 40:
        pay = ((hrs-40)*1.5*rate) + (hrs*rate)
    return pay

hrs = float(raw_input('Enter hours '))
print computepay(hrs, 10.5)
```

Comment: Based on what it should be 498.75?

Comment: So this is part of the question, it is saying that the pay should be 498.75 ->  Put the logic to do the computation of time-and-a-half in a function called computepay() and use the function to do the computation. The function should return a value. Use 45 hours and a rate of 10.50 per hour to test the program (the pay should be 498.75).

Answer (score 0):

Oh never mind!
Found an error on elif pay calculation LOL

def computerpay(hrs, rate):
    if hrs <=40:
        pay = hrs * rate
    elif hrs > 40:
        pay = ((hrs-40)*1.5*rate) + (40*rate)
    return pay

hrs = float(raw_input('Enter hours '))
print computerpay(hrs, 10.5)